# Qual o motivo do erro "unable to auto-detect email address (got 'email@dominio.(none)')"?

Tags: git

Bom dia pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou testando um servidor git em rede. Criei o repositório em um servidor da rede, as configurações estão ok de uma das máquinas de desenvolvimento, pois consegui usar todos os comandos git sem problemas, add, commit, push e etc

Mas, em uma outra máquina, eu recebo o erro do título:

> unable to auto-detect email address (got 'email@dominio.(none)')

Pesquisando aqui eu encontrei um post parecido e com o mesmo erro mas, era pro Git Hub mesmo e no meu caso não ajuda, ou ao menos acredito que não.

Qual seria a causa do erro então?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa definir o e-mail que será usado pelo git para aplicar os commits, através da variável `user.email`.

Você pode usar o seguinte comando para definir:

```
git config --global user.email "seu@email.com"
```

E, aproveitando, configure o nome também:

```
git config --global user.name "Seu Nome"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado... Eu estava usando user.mail np lugar de user.email... Deu certo aqui... Valeu mesmo...